# `Convert mySQL Query to SQLite Using SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am working on a mobile app that is currently using an ajax call to run a mySQL query remotely and return the data as an array. I want to run the query locally using SQLite 3 an iPad. Below is the mySQL query. I am having trouble getting the query to work in SQLite

This is my working mySQL Query

```
SELECT 
 expense_date.expenseDate,
 expenses.cost,
 SUM(expenses.cost) as total,
 expenses.name,
 category.category
 FROM expenses
 INNER JOIN category ON expenses.catID = category.catID
 INNER JOIN expense_date ON expenses.dateID = expense_date.dateID
WHERE expense_date.expenseDate BETWEEN '#from#' AND '#tu#'
  AND expenses.catID != '1F27C7A1-3E16-5087-A313-A47D286A77A5'
  AND expenses.catID != 'DF64C183-5056-A816-1ACA94F902242B61'
  AND expenses.userID = '#userID#'
  AND expenses.accountID = '#accountID#'
Group By expense_date.expenseDate
```

UPDATED MySQL Statement. This statement works in mySQL but not in SQLite 3.

```
SELECT 
     expense_date.expenseDate,
     SUM(expenses.cost) as total
     FROM expenses
     INNER JOIN expense_date ON expenses.dateID = expense_date.dateID 
    WHERE expense_date.expenseDate 
        BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31'  
        AND expenses.catID != '1F27C7A1-3E16-5087-A313-A47D286A77A5' 
        AND expenses.catID != 'DF64C183-5056-A816-1ACA94F902242B61' 
        AND expenses.userID = 'C4C73329-5056-A816-1AB4B9FAE08FDB77' 
        AND expenses.accountID = '46298719-C78A-4CCE-8ADD-A3FD948DF93E' 
        Group By expense_date.expenseDate
```

This is the results of the query. 2014-08-21 has two values for that date: 2000.00 and 372.00 but they are added together and returned as a single value for 2014-08-21.

```
2014-08-01  32.00
2014-08-16  15.00
2014-08-19  513.55
2014-08-21  2372.00
2014-08-22  525.00
2014-08-25  34.55
2014-08-27  52.78
2014-08-31  30.00
```

I need to convert the MySQL query code to SQLite. I did a google search and found some info about using CASE but I am not sure how to construct the sql statement. Your help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry, but `it doesn't work` doesn't work for us too. Please provide a clear error message or a clear result description.

Comment: This query does not make sense to begin with. Which `cost`/`name`/`category` value should be output for a group that has more than one row for the same expense date?

Comment: #php, #CLThe mySQL query works with my data but I have taken out code that I really don't need retrieved. i am posting the new mySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the SQLite sql statement that solved my problem.

```
SELECT expense_date.expenseDate, 
SUM(expenses.cost) AS total 
FROM expenses INNER JOIN expense_date ON expenses.dateID = expense_date.dateID 
WHERE expense_date.expenseDate BETWEEN '"+from+"' AND '"+tu+"' 
AND expenses.catID <> '1F27C7A1-3E16-5087-A313-A47D286A77A5' 
AND expenses.catID <> 'DF64C183-5056-A816-1ACA94F902242B61' Group By expense_date.expenseDate
```

Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query actually doesn't make sense in MySQL, because several of the selected values are indeterminate.  You might try something like this:

```
SELECT ed.expenseDate, SUM(e.cost) as total,
       group_concat(e.name) as names,
       group_concat(c.category) as categories
FROM expenses e INNER JOIN
     category c
     ON e.catID = e.catID INNER JOIN
     expense_date ed
     ON e.dateID = ed.dateID
WHERE ed.expenseDate BETWEEN '#from#' AND '#tu#'  AND
      e.catID <> '1F27C7A1-3E16-5087-A313-A47D286A77A5' AND
      e.catID <> 'DF64C183-5056-A816-1ACA94F902242B61' AND
      e.userID = '#userID#' AND
      e.accountID = '#accountID#'
Group By ed.expenseDate;
```

Comment: #GordonLinoff Thanks for your reply. I eliminated part of the code that wasn't necessary but you code doesn't give the correct totals for the dates. Some dates have more than on cost and other don't. the code above creates a total for each date. Not sure how your code was creating the totals.

Comment: #gordonlinoff I added code update that works in MySQL but doesn't work in SQLite

Comment: I have tried to clarify my question by adding the results I get from the working version of the MySQL SQL statement.

Comment: @user2150327 . . . If you want the detailed data for each date, remove the `group by` and aggregation functions.